# Subtracting NSDecimalNumber swift?

Tags: swift, swift2, subtraction, nsdecimalnumber

I want to subtract one NSDecimalNumber from another simply. For whatever reason, this is not working, and the first NSDecimalNumber is not updating.

Here is my code.

```
func updateTotal(itemAmount amount: NSDecimalNumber) {
    print("before: \(self.total), amount: \(amount)")
    self.total.decimalNumberBySubtracting(amount)
    print("after: \(self.total)")
}
```

Both self.total before and after are not affected by the subtraction. I am using swift 2.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `decimalNumberBySubtracting(amount)` returns a new value, which your code ignores:

```
let res = self.total.decimalNumberBySubtracting(amount)
print("after: \(res)")
```

If you would like to modify `self.total`, you can assign it back (assuming that it is a `var`)

```
self.total = self.total.decimalNumberBySubtracting(amount)
```

Comment: man I have other operations in my code other than subtraction where I reset the value. I think this would be a good time to take a break. thanks for the help